# Transform .wp-video to the native video player of the browser

Tags: hooks, videos

Is there a way to display a video using only the default video player of the browser, without the `mejs` / `wp-video` interface? The additional markup gives me a lot of trouble. I just want to use the `<video>` element, and handle my custom needs with CSS/JS.

I won't say I'm an expert. I have considerable amount of experience with custom templates and hooks, but I can't figure this one out.

Comment: Maybe you could show us a bit of your code for us to be able to help you ?

Comment: I don't have any code yet, because I don't know how to start. I'd like to know if there is a hook for this, or a clue where to start looking.

Comment: I gave you a possible answer with the embed_oembed_html filter

Comment: I am on phone, but give it a try soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the right way digging through the WP documentation: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/wp_video_shortcode/

This code seems to do the trick:

```
function buildVideoPlayer($output, $attr)
{
    // $output contains the default HTML string, created by the WP core
    // $attr is an associative array, which contains the parameters 
    // (src, poster, preload, etc.) specified in the shortcode

    // The following piece of HTML string will replace the default WP video player
    return "<video src='".$attr["mp4"]."'></video>";
}
add_filter("wp_video_shortcode", "buildVideoPlayer", 10, 2);
```

Make sure to pass how many parameters do you want to catch in `add_filter()`. The default value is 1, but `wp_video_shortcode` has 4, and in this code, I needed the 2nd one.

Answer (score -1):

I would try to use the **embed_oembed_html filter**

Here is an ultra basic example

```
add_filter('embed_oembed_html','oembed_video_add_wrapper',10,4);

function oembed_video_add_wrapper( $cache, $url, $attr, $post_ID) {
        return sprintf('<video src="%s">',$url);
}
```

Comment: Why the down vote?

Comment: I did not specify it, but I need this solution to work with videos uploaded to my site.

Comment: It should work too, it interferes with the embed shortcode if I correctly remember.

Comment: I guess it can work in other cases, but I've found a solution better suited for my problem. Thanks for your time.

Comment: No problem, i’m glad for you.